# Easiest way to use startAt to only get new child_added for counting records

Tags: coffeescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm writing an app with angularfire.  It includes a node.js service (running on my own server) that "does stuff" to the data on a regular basis.  I'm trying to write .on handlers to update a "count" field in a parent record.  So I started with:

```
guilds = fb.child('guilds')
guilds.on 'child_added', (guildsnap) ->
  console.log 'First read of guild: ' + guildsnap.name()
  guild_applicants = fb.child('applicants').child(guildsnap.name()) 
  guild_applicants.on 'child_changed', (appsnap) ->
    console.log 'Guild Applicant Changed'
    app = new Applicant(appsnap)
    if app.val.rejected then app.reject()
    if app.val.accepted then app.accept()
  guild_applicants.on 'child_removed', (appsnap) ->
    console.log 'Applicant removed, reducing count'
    fb.child('guilds').child(guildsnap.name()).child('applicant_count').transaction (o) -> o - 1
  guild_applicants.startAt().on 'child_added', (appsnap) ->
    console.log 'Applicant added to ' + guildsnap.name() + ', increasing count'
    fb.child('guilds').child(guildsnap.name()).child('applicant_count').transaction (o) -> o + 1
```

So, when the service first loads, it creates 'on' handlers for the appropriate 'guild_applicants' collection.  The intent is that when applicants are added or removed, the handlers will update the 'applicant_count' field accordingly.

If the service is running when a new guild is created, it works great.  I can create a guild, add applicants, remove applicants, and the applicant_count is updated.  So, e.g., I will have a guild with five applicants, and the applicant_count field will = 5.

But if I stop the service and restart it, the guild_applicant child_added handler immediately finds all those applicants and increments the appliant_count field again.  So eg. I would end up with five applicants, and the appliant_count field will = 10.

From what I've seen, you can add "startAt" to a firebase query, and it will limit the responses.  But I'm not sure the best way to implement that.  It looks like I have to set a priority field, and use that?  It just seems strange that I'm writing custom code for a use case that feels like it ought to be common enough to be part of the library.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**EDIT: Trying to use priority...**

Looking at the same problem, in a different way; I tried to use priorities with Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, and it's not working the way I expect it to...

```
# on the angularfire client...
# the $set works but the $priority and $save seem to do nothing...?
      $scope.guild.$on 'loaded', (model) ->
        console.log 'guild loaded.'
        if not model
          $scope.guild.$priority = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          $scope.guild.$save()
          $scope.guild.$set
            initialized: false

# on the node.js server...

# fb is an object that generates me a root firebase reference based on my fb URL
guilds = fb.child('guilds')
# i want this handler to run on every guild, new and existing, when the service starts
guilds.on 'child_added', (guildsnap) ->
  console.log 'First read of guild: ' + guildsnap.name()
  # do stuff that sets up other handlers for guild child events

# i want this handler to run only on guilds that are actually created
# to perform initialization on the guild record
guilds.startAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).on 'child_added', (guildsnap) ->
  console.log "New Guild Created"
  guild = new Guild(guildsnap)
  guild.initialize()
```

So what happens here is, the 'every guild' .on fires, but the 'initialization' .on doesnt.  I can't tell if the priority is actually being set by angularFire...?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what the count is supposed to represent here. It looks like it should represent all applicants in applicants/$guild_name (literally the number of records there), but your question seems to be asking for only children added/removed since you start observing. What is the underlying use case we're trying to create here?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to keep a count on the number of applicants.  The problem is whenever my node.js restarts, the child_added event gets triggered on every record.  So it increments the count every time it restarts, resulting in a count=10 for 5 actual records on the first restart, a count=15 for 5 on the second restart, etc.

Comment: I have a similar use case with the guilds themselves (the second example).  I want the node.js service to initialize some of the values, but only the first time the guild is added.  Same problem: the child_added handler gets fired every time I restart the node service, which will cause existing guilds to get re-initialized.

Comment: It sounds like you want some initialization to happen on a guild object only the first time it is created. Why not simply have a node.js server run and do the initialization on every child_added call? You can set a sentinel flag like 'initialized: true' to check what records the server still needs to process if the script ever needs to restart.

Comment: That's how I started implementing it; I did it that way for the 'guild' object, but it felt like there ought to be a better way to do it.  It seems like a lot of extra work to go through.  It feels like there ought to be a way I can just start subscribing to new children.